# content (e.g. images) in NuGet Package is ignored with PackageReference

Tags: nuget, packagereference

I have added content (images and txt-files) to my NuGet-Packages. When I install the package to a Project which uses PackageReference (e.g. .NET7-ConsoleApp), the content is ignored. When I install the package to a project which uses packages.config (e.g. .NET Framework 4.8 ConsoleApp), it will be copied to the projects root directory.

Is there another way to install content to the projects root directory which uses PackageReference? Or can .NET7-Projects configured to use packages.config?

Thanks for your help.